# How to update JavaScript libraries without being terrified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, lightbox, bxslider

One of the great things about being a web developer in recent history is all the sharing that's going on, especially with JavaScript libraries. There's all these awesome tools to use: jQuery, jQuery-UI, Lightbox, bxslider, underscore.js, Backbone.js, the list goes on. Then there comes a time when one or more of these libraries need to be updated. But JavaScript runs on the client, it doesn't compile, and it's difficult or impossible to be notified when a problem occurs. **What is the best technique right now to assure that after you update one or more JavaScript libraries, your web application will not start throwing JavaScript errors?**

There's no way the best response to this is to just test. Especially with a complicated application it can be too difficult to go through every possibility and make sure no errors are thrown. What are other web application developers out there doing to make sure they don't have a deployment with an embarassing and crippling JavaScript bug caused by updating?

Comment: You are using a development environment, right?

Comment: That sounds rhetorical.

Comment: One way to ensure that things still work functionally is to have a suite of automated browser tests (utilizing a tool like Selenium) that you run on your development environment.

Comment: Well I think testing is the fundamental way of checking.  Other than that, try praying to the javascript gods.

Comment: The only way to find if there is a problem is to test it. What you can do however is automate the testing so that you don't have to manually do it and potentially forget to test something. With proper unit testing, you shouldn't get the same error twice. When you run into a problem, you create a unit test for that problem so that from then on, that problem is tested for every time you run your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to "just test". What you are asking, essentially, is "How do I test to make sure my software still works?". You can do all the homework you want to see what changed, but **eventually you just need to test your application**.

That being said, there are generic testing tools like [JSLint](http://jslint.com) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.com), but **ultimately your application is going to be unique** enough that you will need to have unit tests to cover the business logic and standard QA for non-standard processes.

Comment: I'm not asking about indeterminate problems like "oh that phrase is worded in a way that sounds negative". A JavaScript exception being thrown happens or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure that things still work functionally is to have a suite of automated browser tests (utilizing a tool like Selenium) that you run on your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really call this "just testing" but unit testing will help do the job.  Write tests once for your app looking for the expected results (good practice either way), then when you update the plugins run these tests again.

http://qunitjs.com/

Nothing beats a good QA and browser testing though.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of other answers already include "test", so hopefully that's obvious at this point.

The other thing that you should ALWAYS do is read the release notes for every single version up to the version that you're upgrading to.  I can't speak intelligently about bxslider or Lightbox, but the other major libraries that you referenced are extremely good at releasing detailed changelogs which will notify you of breaking changes.  You can decide for yourself if any of these changes will have a negative effect on your app ( in addition to testing of course!).